# Run maven compilation twice

Tags: java, maven, ant

I'm in process of migrating ant project to maven and this project is quite unusual: it uses two compilation steps and code generation step between those compilation steps. The whole build process can be described as follows:

1. Compile everything in src directory
2. Run internal java tool, point java to the compiled classes and jars used to compile those classes. This tool generates code based on the compiled classes by using reflection.
3. Compile generated classes and finally assemble a jar.

I found a few links that suggest to create a custom lifecycle but I've no idea where to start.
If someone can point to similar project configuration that would be really great.

What would be the simplest way of achieving this with maven?
I guess I should use ant maven plugin but I still don't understand how to make it compile sources twice and point it to the generated sources after first compilation step.

Comment: I hope you're getting some benefit from Maven in exchange for this headache.

Comment: the only thing I really want to get from maven is its dependency management. Also modern maven is capable to do parallel builds.

Comment: Might be worth looking at Ivy for dependency management. For existing Ant projects with unusual build flows, Ant+Ivy can be a simpler migration path than going directly to Maven. In any event, best of luck with your migration!

Comment: Thanks for pointing on Ivy, but I have to stick to the maven since lots of the other projects already used it. If someone interested - at the moment I've decided to stick with multimodular project configuration - this is not an ideal solution, but it looks like a simple way to do what I wanted. Though I still didn't lose a hope to find a clean, better solution for maven.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I finally figured out how to do that.

Basically I run compiler on different build phases so that compile happens on generate-sources phase, code is generated on process-sources phase and finally compiler makes final compilation on 'compile' phase.

Here is my configuration:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <!-- Code generation, executed after the first compiler pass -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generateCode</id>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
          <mainClass>my.code.Generator</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-target</argument>
            <argument>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</argument>
            <argument>-source</argument>
            <argument>my.code.generator.Configuration</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>


  <!-- Custom compilation mode -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>build-generated-code</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</generatedSourcesDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone.

**UPDATE** You may probably notice that compiler unnecessarily compiles all the sources on final compiler pass. To fine tune your particular compiler pass you may want to use 'exclude'/'include' configuration for your project.

Comment: This code specifies the default `generatedSourcesDirectory`, which is redundant. Minor nit. Anyway, very helpful example.

Comment: Note the <id>default-compile</id> is both magical and required.

Comment: Thanks @AlicePurcell, this was the key to solving the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you better create two separate Maven projects. Put the (static) Java sources into the first project. Put the dynamic stuff into the second project and add a reference to the first project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.yourgroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>sub-module-1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, build and install the first project:

```
mvn install
```

After that you should be able to build the second project.

Comment: I thought about that but it seemed to be excessive for me and a bit confusing. The generated code is not that big and is closely related to the sources within the original package. So, if possible, I'd keep one project.

Answer (score 1):

[Example: Configuring compile to run twice](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html#Example%3a_Configuring_compile_to_run_twice)

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.5</source>
    <target>1.5</target>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-compile</id>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/cli/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>build-java14-cli</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.3</source>
        <target>1.3</target>
        <includes>
          <include>**/cli/*</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Adjust this configuration to your needs

Comment: This seem to be very close to what I need but I don't see a simple way to embed code generation step between the given compilation steps. Probably I missed some very basic maven feature but it seems to me that it's not possible to refer to the other plugin's execution phase in the other plugin, is it?