# Creating a subset of an artifact

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven project from which I require to produce a jarfile compiled with Java 7 for all the classes, and another jarfile for a subset of the classes compiled with Java 6. I know that I should produce ony one artifact pr project, what is the best was to split this up to achive my goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it matter to you if you have to run two separate builds to produce both artifacts? If not, you could easily achieve this with [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). You could set up each JDK profile to produce artifacts with different classifiers to distinguish them.

Personally, I prefer not to do use profiles for this. Two alternative approaches would be to have either a single Maven module with plugin customisations to perform two separate sets of compilation and artifact packaging operations, or to move to a multi-module Maven build with explicit separation based on the target JDK. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21344220/48340) for example.) The former would make the pom.xml harder to maintain but result in a single neater structure. You might find that you spend a lot of time tweaking includes/excludes to specify what goes into each artifact. The latter would result in a more complicated project structure but there would be no doubts what source files go into what artifact.

The idiomatically correct Maven approach would be to split your codebase into a multi-module project with separate Java 6 and 7 modules, each with its own pom.xml. Each can specify different source/target version and only contain the appropriate source files. The Java 7 module can depend on and re-package the Java 6 classes into its own artifact (using [dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html)/[assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) plugins), or even just reference the Java 6 module's sources directly using a relative path.